# Zooming images in an Ionic PWA

Tags: image, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I am looking to pinch/zoom images in an Ionic PWA. I can build PWA’s which work for zooming (the whole window zooms) when opened in a browser, but as soon as I save to Standalone mode this becomes disabled  I assume this is due to the metadata provided when creating standalone mode.

I’ve tried the ionic-img-viewer plug-in and it doesn’t help.

I don’t know where else to go with this.

Thanks for any pointers

Shane

Comment: Welcome to SO Shane! Please share your current implementation code that is relevant to your question. Its hard to help you in vacuum